# Setting data into a Kendo DataSource Without Ajax

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have some client-side JSON and want to use to "quickly" experiment with various controls without writing all the REST API calls.  All I want to do is point any given Kendo DataSource to the local array of data I already have instead of writing all the extra's...but nothing I do works.

I have tried various online examples...can someone direct me to something that actually works?

**EXAMPLE:**
This particular example is for their Donut Chart using Angular, but I cant use their data calls because of CORS & I am getting tired of writing a new set of REST calls every time I merely want to experiment with a particular control.

```
var data = [{ ... }, { ... }]

$scope.screenResolution = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    // I dont want this at the moment
    //transport: {
    //    read: {
    //        url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/dataviz/js/screen_resolution.json",
    //        dataType: "json"
    //    }
    //},
    sort: {
        field: "order",
        dir: "asc"
    },
    group: {
        field: "year"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datasource has a data property that you can set to a local array.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-data